# express serve js files separately

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My webapp loads far too slowly when using the express.static middleware to serve
all my js files so I wanted to try to serve each js file only when needed (when serving the html from jade that uses the js file). I've tried using `.sendFile()` but it doesn't seem to be working, though I can't tell if that's because it can't be used for my purpose or if I just don't know how to use it.

Is there a way to dynamically serve up js files so as not to require load time until necessary, or should I just suck it up, minimize my js, and serve it all up staticly at the beginning?

Comment: We need to see your code.  Static file serving should be very fast if done right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the simplest solution for you problem is to use the 
async attribute in script tag

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

```
 A script that will be run asynchronously as soon as it is available:
<script src="demo_async.js" async></script>
```

Or use defer attribute

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

```
A script that will not run until after the page has loaded:
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Ok, this brings up what may be a critical misunderstanding on my part as well as a solution to the problem, do I need to.specify on the server that certain (or all) js files are to be served (via static middleware or otherwise) or will the across automatically be loaded from the server based on the src attribute of the script tag?

Comment: You can use the static middleware. The browser not wait the js to download. And continue to parse the site.. Just put the defer/async in the script tag of the file.
You have to change only the client side.

Comment: Their is a problem?

if it helps you don't forget to upvote the answerer!

Comment: I don't have high enough reputation to upvote yet, but I think I figured out the problem and the solution. I was misunderstanding how express.static works, I thought it sent all the static files to the user when first visiting the site and that's what was causing a long loading time, but I think now that it instead just makes those files available to be referenced from the app (via src attribute) and that more javascript files won't make my app load slower and the beginning, I should have done more testing before posting my question, but your answer helped, so thanks!

Comment: close the question by put the V (if you can) so the question not will be on unanswared question... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you use in server, setup nginx for serve static file :D